# Duvida sobre Design Patterns - Idempotency Messages

Tags: c#, terminologia, idempotência

Estou tentando criar um exemplo de aplicação que possa fazer a chamada de uma função/método e que após um determinado tempo ele verifique se o processo já foi executado, se não, chama  novamente a mesma função/método e verificar o andamento anterior se esta sendo executado ou se já acabou e devolver o retorno do processo.

Já procurei bastante, mas o não encontrei um exemplo que possa ser seguido.
Os links abaixo descrevem o que realmente o Design Patterns - Idempotency Messages faz.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn589781.aspx

http://blog.jonathanoliver.com/idempotency-patterns/

Estou tentando da seguinte forma;

```
using System;

namespace Idempotent_Messages
{
    public class Program
    {
        static IdePotencyHelper idePotencyHelper = new IdePotencyHelper();
        public static int passo = 1;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {          
            var func = new Funcionario();
            var command = new CqrsBase<Int32, Funcionario>();
            command.Execute(func);

            command.IdPotency((f) =>
            {
                var funcBanco = new Funcionario();
                funcBanco.Id = 1;

                return f.Id == funcBanco.Id;
            },
            (x)=> { return x.Id; }
            , func);
        }
    }

    public class Funcionario
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class CqrsBase<T, TArgs> 
    {
        public T Execute(TArgs args)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public static class CqrsBase
    {
        public static TReturn IdPotency<TReturn, TArgs>(this CqrsBase<TReturn, TArgs> cqrs, Func<TArgs,bool> verify, Func<TArgs, TReturn> existsFunc, TArgs args)
        {
            var existe = verify(args);
            if (existe)
            {
                return existsFunc(args);
            }
            else
            {
                return cqrs.Execute(args);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O Design Patterns - Idempotency

Uma operação é idempotente caso não tenha efeitos adicionais se for chamado mais de uma vez com os mesmos parâmetros. Você não pode controlar como sua API pública é chamada por seus clientes, então você deve se certificar de que não leva a nenhum efeito indesejado se eles repetem suas chamadas uma e outra vez.

Uma solução comum é fornecer uma ID de correlação para qualquer operação potencialmente alterada pelo estado. O serviço verifica em algum repositório se a solicitação foi processada. Se sim, a resposta previamente armazenada deve ser fornecida.

Aqui está um fluxograma que mostra a comunicação com uma identificação de correlação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Imagem copiada do site.](https://dotnetcodr.com/2013/12/16/a-model-soa-application-in-net-part-1-the-fundamentals/)

O problema é que não sei como fazer para criar um identificador para cada processo armazenar seu status e após o tempo determinador verificar o processo pelo identificador.

Comment: Nao é por mal, mas voce precisa melhorar muito a qualidade do seu código.

Comment: na realidade, tenho que reave-lo por completo, em um blog que encontrei achei uma boa descrição do assunto. http://blog.jonathanoliver.com/idempotency-patterns/, mas não tem um exemplo de aplicação.

Comment: @BrunoCosta, fiz uma edição melhorada , já bem próxima do que realmente preciso.

Comment: O que eu eu nao percebi é o que isto tem a ver com repetir tarefas após um determinado periodo de tempo...

Comment: Você entendeu o conceito de idempotency-patterns, ??

Comment: Já conhecia. Idempotency nao é um padrao, mas sim uma propriedade/caracteristica de determinada operacao.

Comment: entendi, reveja os conceitos então a própria microsoft fala que é um patterns . https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn589781.aspx

Comment: Nao é preciso ler esse artigo. A [wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) diz logo que Idempotency é uma propriedade na primeira frase `... is the property of certain operations in mathematics and computer science`

Comment: @BrunoCosta, ok, o que eu preciso é o que esta no artigo, e não o que você postou.

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esta função não faz aquilo que voce especificou, mas está mais perto de atingir o seu objetivo. Ela experimenta executar a função `action` um determinado número de vezes. Se a `action` completar dentro do tempo especificado então o valor é retornado. Adapte a função para cumprir o seu requisito adicional de completar uma chamada anterior.

```
static async Task<T> Retry<T>(Func<T> action, TimeSpan timeout, int? attempts = 3){
    for(int i = 0; i < attempts; ++i){
        var task = Task.Factory
            .FromAsync(action.BeginInvoke(null, null), r => action.EndInvoke(r));
        var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout);
        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, timeoutTask);
        if(completedTask == task){
            return task.Result; 
        }
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
        $"Was not able to execute the task within {attempts} attempts");
}
```

Para usar:

```
Retry(() => 4, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Result.Dump();
Retry(() => 4, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)).Result.Dump();
Retry(() => {Thread.Sleep(500); return 4;}, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)).Result.Dump();
Retry(() => {Thread.Sleep(500); return 4;}, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)).Result.Dump();
```

Pedidos de clarificacoes dos comentários:

> **Como posso identificar qual a action esta sendo executada**

Uma `task` está a ser executada se o seu status for igual a `Running`

```
var task = Task.Delay(500);
task.Status == TaskStatus.Running // está a ser executada
```

Uma outra forma menos correta é assumir que a sua `Task` está a correr até ela completar o `await` quer ela saia por excepcao, ou por processo completo

```
var task = Task.Delay(500);
await task; //a task está a ser executada até á próxima instrucao
Debug.Assert(task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) // a task completou
```

Entao verificar se um processo terminou em 10 minutos pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
async Task<bool> Timeout(Action action, TimeSpan timeout){
    var task = Task.Factory
        .FromAsync(action.BeginInvoke(null, null), r => action.EndInvoke(r));
    var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout);
    var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, timeoutTask);
    return completedTask == task;
}

Timeout(()=> Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)).Result.Dump();
```

Se prestou atenção viu que o código é semelhante ao código que eu mostrei anteriormente para o `Retry`.

> Só quero manda executa novamente se não tive nada estive sendo feito
>   daquela mesma action

Eu não sei o que isto quer dizer. Se voce mandou executar uma task então, a partir do momento em que ela entra no estado `TaskStatus.Running` ela já executou alguma coisa.

Ou seja, voce nunca vai mandar executar nada novamente porque alguma coisa já foi executada.

---

Parece que a pergunta mudou um bocado, mas criticas á parte...

> O problema é que não sei como fazer para criar um identificador para
>   cada processo armazenar seu status e após o tempo determinador
>   verificar o processo pelo identificador.

A única forma que conheço de resolver este problema é criar um identificador quando cria o processo **e fornecer esse identificador ao consumidor da API**.

Exemplo minimalista:

```
/*********** API ***********/
private Dictionary<string, Task<int>> tarefas = new Dictionary<string, Task<int>>();
private Random r = new Random();

private async Task<int> Tarefa(){
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    return r.Next();
}

public string CriaTarefa(){
    var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    tarefas.Add(id, Tarefa());
    return id;
}

public int? VerificaTarefa(string id){
    Task<int> tarefa;
    if(!tarefas.TryGetValue(id, out tarefa)){
        return null;
    }
    if(!tarefa.IsCompleted){
        return null;
    }
    return tarefa.Result;
}

/*********** Cliente ***********/
var id = CriaTarefa();

while(VerificaTarefa(id) == null){
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}

VerificaTarefa(id).Dump();
```

**Existem técnicas melhores que evitam o *polling* da operação**

Em vez de verificar o processo, aquilo que voce deve fazer é criar um evento que permita que o cliente seja notificado.

```
/*********** API ***********/   
public class Tarefa{
    public event EventHandler<int> OperationCompleted;
    private Random r = new Random();

    public async void CriaTarefa(){
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        OperationCompleted?.Invoke(this, r.Next());
    }

}

/*********** Cliente ***********/
var tarefa = new Tarefa();
tarefa.OperationCompleted += (ctx, r) => r.Dump();
tarefa.CriaTarefa();
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6));
```

Comment: Mas não é isso que entendi que foi perguntado. Eu entendi que quer saber como retornar o resultado de uma operação já realizada previamente. E isso não tem nada a ver com "Retry".

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi A minha resposta foi para a primeira versao da pergunta. `se não, **chama novamente a mesma função/método** e verificar o andamento anterior se esta sendo executado ou se já acabou e devolver o retorno do processo.`. Nao sei se vou editar ou nao a resposta. mas se editar eu aviso-o

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi Editei a respsota.