# O que é "Idempotency Messages", "idempotente", "idempotência"?

Tags: terminologia, idempotência

Tenho uma pergunta sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220584/duvida-sobre-design-patterns-idempotency-messages), e um [artigo](http://blog.jonathanoliver.com/idempotency-patterns/) sobre o assunto até mesmo na [Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence), mas ainda não compreendi o assunto, portanto as perguntas são,

- O que é *Idempotency Messages*?
- Como e onde deve ser utilizado?
- Exemplo simples de uso?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Uma operação idempotente pode ser entendida como algo que estabelece um valor ou estado ao invés de modificá-lo.

Um exemplo simples pode ser o saldo bancário. Imagine o extrato abaixo:

```
Data             Valor        Operação
01/01/2017      100,00        Abertura de conta + Depósito inicial
02/01/2017      -14,99        Netflix
03/01/2017      -20,00        Refeição
04/01/2017      -30,00        Táxi
01/02/2017        5,01        Saldo Atual
02/02/2017      +14,99        Extorno - Netflix
```

Se você quer saber o saldo desta conta no dia 06/01/2007 você não pode apenas observar o último valor processado, porque ele é um *modificador* (-30 reais no dia 4/01). Você precisa levar em consideração todas as modificações até encontrar o primeiro valor definido por uma *operação idempotente* - neste caso, a abertura de conta com o valor de 100 reais.

A mensagem no dia 01/02 também pode ser considerada uma operação idempotente: Muitos sistemas se utilizam deste mecanismo para facilitar avaliações de estado. No exemplo acima você não precisa recalcular todos os valores até a primeira operação para determinar o saldo atual.

Comment: Uma operação desse tipo necessariamente deve ser um valor inicial? Digo, se no teu exemplo adicionarmos um lançamento chamado `saldo atualizado`, com o valor das modificações, seria também um `idempotente`?

Exemplo: `04/01/2017      35,00        Saldo atual`

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade sim, se sua operação estabelece um estado (ao invés de modificá-lo) ela pode ser consideda como idempotente também.

Answer (score 6):

**- O que é Idempotency Messages?**

Primeiro é necessário compreender o conceito de idempotência: uma operação ou mensagem que pode ser aplicada diversas vezes sem alterar o resultado final.

**- Como e onde deve ser utilizado?**

Pode ser aplicado em comunicações assíncronas e/ou por mensagens, por exemplo. Uma mensagem recebe um identificador. O destinatário deve entender que uma segunda mensagem com mesmo identificador não deve alterar o estado final

**- Exemplo simples de uso?**

Imagine um sistema que recebe a mensagem:

```js
{
"Identificador" : "789456",
"Comando" : "CancelarPedido",
"CodigoPedido" : "A258963"
}
```

Suponha que o sistema recebe essa mensagem pela primeira vez, ele cancela o pedido. Quando este sistema receber uma segunda mensagem como mesmos `Identificador`, `Comando` e `CodigoPedido` deve ser aceita como válida e retornar o mesmo resultado que a primeira ocorrência dela teve. O resultado final da mensagem, o cancelamento do pedido, não será alterado por mensagens subsequentes.

Há um [episódio do Podcast da Lambda3 sobre Filas e Mensagerias](https://www.lambda3.com.br/2019/07/lambda3-podcast-150-filas-e-mensageria/) que discute cenários sobre o tema e como esse conceito deve ser aplicado.

Answer (score 5):

Vamos entrar na teoria sobre a idempotência antes de aplicá-la em um exemplo prático, até mesmo porque após compreender o que é a idempotência, você pode OU não aplicá-la dependendo da sua situação.

### O que é idempotência?

Idempotência é a propriedade que permite uma operação ser aplicada mais de uma vez, sem que o resultado seja alterado.

### Onde aplicar idempotência se torna interessante?

Quando existir a possibilidade de processamento duplicado de informação, onde irá causar problemas de inconsistência (principalmente no negócio).

No caso de comunicações assíncronas, utiliza-se o termo de *Idempotency Messages*, onde juntamente com a mensagem é enviada uma propriedade (um ID ou um token), que irá unicamente identificar a mensagem.

Você pode verificar através dessa propriedade se a mensagem já foi processada (ou não verificar), e tratar de acordo (apenas ignorar a mensagem ou reprocessar)

Outro exemplo seria quando houve uma falha na requisição, e você não tem certeza se a sua solicitação foi de fato atendida pelo servidor, imagine o seguinte cenário:

```
1) (Saldo total) R$1000,00
2) Transferência de R$100,00 para minha conta (POST /transfers?amount=100)
3) 200 OK | (Saldo total) R$900,00
4) Transferência de R$900,00 para minha conta (POST /transfers?amount=900)
5) CONNECTION TIMEOUT | (Saldo total) ? 
6) Transferência de R$900,00 para minha conta (POST /transfers?amount=900)
7) 200 OK | (Saldo total) -R$900,00
```

Quando houve um timeout na conexão, não tivemos a resposta se a operação foi realizada ou não, no nosso caso o servidor já havia processado e descontado R$900,00, deixando nossa conta zerada. Uma nova requisição realizou uma outra trasferência de R$900,00, deixando nossa conta negativa.

Para este exemplo, caso houvesse um token de idempotência implementado, o fluxo ficaria desta forma:

```
Antes de realizar a operação, meu token de idempotência é gerado com o valor 98s0a9F

1) (Saldo total) R$1000,00
2) Transferência de R$100,00 para minha conta (POST /transfers?amount=100&tk=98s0a9F)
3) 200 OK | (Saldo total) R$900,00

Nova operação, meu token de idempotência é gerado com o valor f019a8f

4) Transferência de R$900,00 para minha conta (POST /transfers?amount=900&tk=f019a8f)
5) CONNECTION TIMEOUT | (Saldo total) ? 
6) Transferência de R$900,00 para minha conta (POST /transfers?amount=900&tk=f019a8f)
7) 200 OK | (Saldo total) R$0,00
```

Para este segundo exemplo, o servidor vai identificar que para o token `f019a8f` uma operação já foi realizada, e somente vai enviar o resultado da operação que ocorreu com sucesso, sem realizar uma nova transferência.

### Certo e onde eu consigo ver essa idempotência funcionando?

A [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api/idempotent_requests) possui um mecanismo bem interessante de idempotência para garantir que nenhuma operação seja realizada sem que de fato se tenha a intenção de realizá-la.

É importante destacar também que no caso do HTTP, existem métodos que são [idempotentes por padrão](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-23) e não necessitam deste tratamento.

Comment: Perdi o prazo de aplicar a recompensa e o sistema deu automaticamente metade pra outra nova mais votada, mas eu acho que esta aqui ficou melhor elaborada. Os exemplos e descrição estão bons. Só quis mencionar para que ninguem pense que os 25 foram na outra por uma escolha voluntária. De qq forma, no mínimo deixo meu +1 aqui

Comment: Não esquenta @Bacco :) fica pra próxima